# Как обработать картинку?

Tags: java

Обработкой картинок не занимался. Есть картинка - на белом фоне синие точки. Размер точек одинаковый и больше одного пикселя. Необходимо подсчитать количество точек. В каком направлении необходимо двигаться чтобы решить эту задачу?

Comment: 1) Поискать биндинг OpenCV для java 2) найти контуры 3) Пример на питоне https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/master/opencv__examples/find_objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего использовать OpenCV библиотеку. 
 1.конвертируешь картинку в чб
 2.ищешь края
 3.ищешь контуры
Поскольку кроме точек ничего нету, то размер массива(листа) контуров и будет количество этих самых точек.